# How to color name last name in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I want to only color last name.
For example:

```
Rohit Kumar Singh
Rahul Ranjan Singh
Kaushal Kishor Singh
```

I want to only color last name. Is is possible with or without vba.

Answer (score 1):

In vba this will do it:

```
Sub rohit()
Dim cel As Range
Dim i As Integer
For Each cel In Selection.Cells
    If cel.value <> "" Then
        Dim lastname As String
        if Ubound(Split(cel, " ")) > 0 then
             lastname = Split(cel, " ")(1)
        Else 
             lastname = cel.Value
        End If
        For i = 1 To Len(cel)
            If Mid(cel, i, Len(lastname)) = lastname Then
                cel.Characters(i, Len(lastname)).Font.Color = vbRed
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

This will change the second word in the string.

The key to which word is changed is with this line:

```
lastname = Split(cel, " ")(1)
```

The `Split` function returns an array, the first word is 0, the second is 1 and so forth.  The number after the function dictates which word in that array is returned.

If the number of words are unknown and the last word is wanted then use:

```
lastname = Split(cel, " ")(Ubound(Split(cel, " ")))
```

This gets the upper bound of the array or last one. If you want the second to last and it will vary then use:

```
lastname = Split(cel, " ")(Ubound(Split(cel, " "))-1)
```

This will allow you to get any word depending on your desired pattern.

Also it based on the selection.

Comment: @RohitSingh If it helped please consider marking as correct.

Comment: rohit
kkkk
rrrr"

"bharat"
kkkk
ppp"

"raju"
kkkk
rrer                                                     I want to color all the string after first line break. Is if possible

Comment: @RohitSingh I changed it to find the second word and change the color of that word